# Error while casting between Button and my custom class MyButton which extends Button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an android application using Android Studio.
I have written a custom class named 'MyButton' which extends Button.
I also have a resource file with several buttons.
At the execution, I get an exception saying that I cannot cast Button to MyButton.
The line is :

`myButton = (MyButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);`

button1 is the id of a Button declared in the resource file.
myButton is a data of type MyButton class.

Comment: You are assigning a superclass object to subclass. But you are not typecasting it. Please Cast the superclass object to subclass and try once. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I made a error in the question above.
You should read
myButton = (**MyButton**) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

Comment: post your custom button class code and xml

Comment: `public class MyButton extends Button {
    TemporisationBouton pCountDownTimer;
    private class TemporisationBouton extends CountDownTimer {
...
    }
    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        pCountDownTimer = new TemporisationBouton(5000, 5000);
    }
    public void start() {
        this.setEnabled(false);
        pCountDownTimer.start();
    }
}`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
...
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:text="Coureur 1"
  android:clickable="true" />
...
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: you must change in xml Button to you class full name

Comment: I changed in the xml Button by com.app.MyButton.
Then I get another exception:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #195: Binary XML file line #195: Error inflating class com.app.MyButton
                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #195: Error inflating class com.app.MyButton
                 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
...
Line 195 is the line com.app.MyButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't attach the layout source (XML), I am not sure if you used your custom MyButton class for creating a button like ***R.id.button1***. You should do something like in your layout XML:

```
<your-package-name.MyButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Coureur 1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Your button title"/>
```

Comment: I made an error in the copy/paste.
You should read _MyButton_ instead of _Button_

Comment: I changed in the xml Button by com.app.MyButton. Then I get another exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #195: Binary XML file line #195: Error inflating class com.app.MyButton Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #195: Error inflating class com.app.MyButton Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet] at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204) ... Line 195 is the line com.app.MyButton

Comment: You should have a constructor into your custom **MyButton** class like this: `public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`

Comment: Might also need another constructor like: `public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)`

Comment: However, you can accept my edit solving your copy/paste errors. That could help others to find a better question to answer.

Comment: I added the constructor public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

It works.

Answer (score 1):

**You can not do this.**

Because you created MyButton using Button. Button is independent but MyButton depends on Button. When you declare

```
MyButton button = (Button) findByElementById()
```

**It causes Compiler error.** Because Compiler knows MyButton is a Button Only Button is not MyButton.

But You can do like this

```
Button button = new MyButton()
```

Because MyButton() is a Button()

**or**

```
Button button = (Button) new MyButton()
```

But Here You don't need cast MyButton() to Button() because Compiler already knows MyButton() is a Button()

In java you can only Upcasting and Downcasting. Have a look on Java Downcasting and Upcasting rules that will make you more clear

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this cast you can do the following:

First, Your MyButton class must use this constructor:

```
MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

Then in your layout use your custom button:

```
<com.mypackagename.MyButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
```

Finally, you can refer to your custom button

```
MyButton button = findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with API 26, `findViewById()` uses inference for its return type, so you don't need to cast. You can use below code for creating your object

```
MyButton myButton = (MyButton) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCoureur1);
```

Comment: When I use the proposed code above, I get an error and can't compile.
Incompatible type
Required: MyButton
Found: android.view.View

Comment: @HeudePascal : are you using api 26 or above for development?

Comment: Not sure I'm using API 26.
Compile sdk version is API 23

Comment: then it won't work you should update your api version to 26 or higher and try.

Comment: if you want solution without changing api version, you need to cast `myButton = (MyButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);` using your sub class not Button which is superclass.

Comment: I changed the class Button into android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.
I added the cast (Mybutton).
now, I get the exception impossible cast between MyButton and android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton

Comment: Extract from my xml:
`<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:text="Coureur 1"
android:clickable="true" />`

Comment: are you using this in fragment?

Comment: as shown you should replace `R.id.button1` with `R.id.buttonCoureur1`

Comment: Yes, the source code is in the method `onCreateView` inside a class which extends Fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can casting like this:

```
public class MyButton extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton {

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}

MyButton myButton = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

API level 26 above does not require casting type declarations. As long as the child class still maintains the constructor must belong to the parent, there will be no errors

Comment: I'm not using API 26, but API 23 (as per "compile sdk version").
I changed Button into android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton but I still get a cast exception